# Is there any option of cold-bootstraping a persistent store in Kafka streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have been working on kafka-streams for a couple of months. We are using RocksDB to store data. Now, changelog topic keeps data of only a few days and if our application's persistent stores have data of few months. How will store state be restored if a partition is moved from one node to another(which I think, happens through changelog).

Also, if the node goes containing active task and a new node is introduced. So, the replica will be promoted to active and a new replica will start building on this new node. So, if changelog has only few days of data the new replica will have only that data, instead of original few months.

So, is there any option where we can transfer data to a replica from the active store rather than changelog(as it only has fraction of data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changelog topics that are used to backup stores don't have a retention time but are configured with log-compaction enabled (cf. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction). Thus, it's guaranteed that no data is lost no matter how long you run. The changelog topic will always contain the exact same data as your RocksDB stores.

Thus, for fail-over or scale-out, when a task migrates and a store need to be rebuild, it will be a complete copy of the original store.

Comment: So, for achieving replication of data in a standby replica once, we replicate it thrice? (1* in standby replica, 1 * in changelog topic and 1* in replication of changelog topic)

Comment: No. There will be only one changelog topic. The active task is the only one that writes to the topic. Standby tasks only read from the topic to build up the local RocksDB. If failover happens, the Standby becomes the active task and uses the existing changelog topic.

Comment: But kafka topics are also fault-tolerant. So, change-log partitions should have some replication? And in terms of disk space, we have active rocksdb, replica rocksdb and changelog topic.

Comment: Ah -- I see what you mean now. Yes, changelog topics are replicated to make sure no data is lost. Using Standby replicas is not related to guard agains data loss, but to provide fast fail-over. If you don't have Standby replicas, in error case the new tasks must read the whole changelog topic to recreate the state, and this can take some time depending on the size of your state. But even without Standby replicas you will never loose data as it's store reliably in the changelog topic.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax does this happen with the same application.id? Let's say I'm running 5 Java instances reading from a topic with 50 partitions. All instances share the same application.id and they share those 50 partitions. When the 5th is gone, rebalance kicks in. Since the offsets are kept with application.id and the 5th comes back on a different node, it wouldn't read from the changelog and lose its state, am I right? Please also see this thread on Confluent mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/confluent-platform/MRjz8MRBDCg/07rW4UxTAQAJ

Comment: In case of failover, when the instance comes back on a new node, it will first read the complete changelog topic to restore the state and afterwards resumes processing from the committed input topic offsets.This restore process is independent and works the same way with or without StandbyTasks.